# Linux bash script to add data to database

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting, mariadb

I am trying to write a bash script that will pull data from a csv file and put it in a format where I can place it in a database. The csv file has about 1000 rows and 8 columns. When I use the command line I can get the data formatted exactly how I want. I am using the latest version of CentOS minimal install.

(edit) A sample of the csv file is:

```
[root@node72 ~]# cat users72.csv | head
```

> msza907,Matyas Szabo,Men,Fencing,FE,germany
>
> krut825,Kristian Ruth,Men,Sailing,SA,norway
>
> sdon251,Samuil Donkov,Men,Shooting,SH,bulgaria
>
> aroa777,Andres Roa,Men,Football,FB,colombia

The code I use in the CLI is:

```
# cat users72.csv | awk -F',' '{ print "INSERT INTO athletes (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation) VALUES (""\""$1"\""", ""\""$3"\""", ""\""$5"\""");"}'
```

A sample of the output looks like this:

> INSERT INTO athletes (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation) VALUES ("gjan887", "Men", "AR");
>
> INSERT INTO athletes (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation) VALUES ("ifet740", "Women", "VO");
>
> INSERT INTO athletes (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation) VALUES ("apet755", "Men", "AT");
>
> INSERT INTO athletes (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation) VALUES ("fnep723", "Men", "SH");
>
> INSERT INTO athletes (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation) VALUES ("othi288", "Women", "BK");

This syntax isn't exactly correct for mysql because I need an id number which was what I was using the script for. The id number has to increment by odd numbers so 1, 3, 5, ect, ect. The problem with my script is that when I run it and save it into a file I plan to use to import the data into a database it prints one line with the id and username then the next line has other data I don't need and I can figure it out.

Below is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
inputData=$(cat /root/users72.csv);
((id=1))
for athleteTable in $inputData
do
    echo "$athleteTable" | awk -F',' '{ print "INSERT INTO athletes (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation) VALUES ('$id', " "\""$1"\"" ", " "\""$3"\"" ", " "\""$5"\""");"}'
    ((id=id+2))
done > /root/users72.sql
```

a sample of the users72.sql file looks like this:

> INSERT INTO athletes (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation) VALUES (1, "msza907", "", "");
>
> INSERT INTO athletes (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation) VALUES (3, "Szabo", "Fencing", "germany");
>
> INSERT INTO athletes (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation) VALUES (5, "krut825", "", "");
>
> INSERT INTO athletes (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation) VALUES (7, "Ruth", "Sailing", "norway");
>
> INSERT INTO athletes (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation) VALUES (9, "sdon251", "", "");
>
> INSERT INTO athletes (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation) VALUES (11, "Donkov", "Shooting", "bulgaria");

I have been banging my head against the wall for the last 7 hours trying to get this to work, changing syntax going over other examples and I'm starting to think there is a glitch in the OS. I would love it if someone knows what is wrong or knows a simpler way to accomplish this task could help me out. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just saying: not everything should be done using the "lowest level" of programming tools (aka shell scripts). You see, **parsing** CSV is much more than just splitting around "," strings for example. Depending where your data is coming from, your simple way of getting the CSV data might fail you pretty soon. My personal recommendation: use that "real" language (java, python, c++) that you are most familiar with; find a good CSV parser library ... and write a "real program" to do this.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but unfortunately one of the requirements for this task is to only use bash scripting. I would love to use python or ruby, would make my life a lot easier for sure but its not allowed.

Comment: Then I see three options: A) hope that somebody comes by and helps with this question ;-) B) still write stuff in python and use that bash script to **call** that python script under the covers (hey, whats the difference between calling awk and python anyway) C) talk to the people who gave you that strange requirement. You see, unless this is for education purpose, it is really the **wrong** approach to "use a hammer" when the task at hand is about getting screws into the wall. And when you are the engineer responsible for implementing things: **speak up**!

Comment: You need to show some sample data from your input CSV file!

Comment: Well this does happen to be for educational purposes so i can't really argue my way out of it and believe me I tried.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @GhostCat for sure, parsing a CSV is much more complicated than just splitting on comma, though some trivial CSVs might work.  Often, though, a CSV can contain commas within a field, so splitting on comma would break things.

That said, your problem here with why the script isn't doing what you want is you're letting word splitting happen on the contents of the file and trying to `awk` each "word".  You should just increment the counter inside `awk` and let it handle reading the file for you.  Assuming you were happy with the original `awk` command you could do it like:

```
 awk -F',' 'BEGIN {id=1} {print "INSERT INTO athletes (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation) VALUES ( " id " \47"$1"\47, \47"$3"\47, \47"$5"\47);";id+=2}' users72.csv
```

Where we create a local `id` variable and increment it by 2 for each line.  I also used the octal escape to print single quotes around each field instead of using lots of quotes and escapes as you had been doing. Feel free to go back to your way if you prefer it (or use `\42` for double quote if you want those instead).  Finally, I changed it so `awk` just opens the file itself and we can avoid the `cat` and pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

It would be a lot simpler to say something like

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'users72.csv'
    INTO TABLE athletes
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ...
    (id, username, gender, sport_abbreviation)
    ;
```

No need for awk; much faster; etc.

[*Reference*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)

**Addenda**

If you don't need all the columns, ...

Plan A:  `LOAD` into a tmp table, then `INSERT SELECT` to copy the ones you want into the real table.

Plan B:  `LOAD` the unneeded columns into `@variables` (that you will do nothing with).

Comment: The problem with that is I only wand specific field not all of the columns of the users72.csv file.

Comment: I added two suggestions on how to do that.